# Using a public function

Tags: ms-access

I have a public function in my db. It basically adds 3 days not counting weekends to a entered date.
It is named addworkingdays.

Now that I have that I want to use it in an afterupdate

I want to say if the review date is not null then addworkingdays to review date

I tried this

```
 Private Sub txt_DueDate_AfterUpdate()
     if(isnull("reviewdate", "", AddWorkingDays([ReviewDate]))
 End Sub
```

it did not work.

I tested it in the expression builder by simply saying =AddWorkingDays([ReviewDate])

And it worked

I am trying to learn VBA

Comment: Does user enter value in both textboxes? So every time someone changes DueDate and there is a value in ReviewDate, 3 days will be added. Do you really want that?

Answer (score 1):

The function is IIf() not If().

Is field a date/time type? Cannot set field equal to empty string.

Field or textbox name should not be between quote marks.

Missing paren for IsNull() function.

And you need to set something to results of function, like:

`Me.txt_DueDate = IIf(IsNull(Me.ReviewDate), Null, AddWorkingDays(Me.ReviewDate))`

Or this approach;

`If Not IsNull(Me.ReviewDate) Then Me.txt_DueDate = AddWorkingDays(Me.ReviewDate)`

Also, I think you probably want to use ReviewDate AfterUpdate instead and simplify expression:

`Me.txt_DueDate = AddWorkingDays(Me.ReviewDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this

```
Private Sub ReviewDate_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txt_DueDate = AddWorkingDays(Me.ReviewDate)
    Me.Recalc
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense than your original code. I don't think Me.Recalc is necessary.